# Move a logical partition to a primary and change MBR to GPT without data loss

Tags: partitioning, gpt, mbr

After long search, I havent find anything so ive decided to create my own post.

This is a gparted screenshot:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdlCO.jpg)

I have 2 question:

How can I move my logical partition (sda5) situated on extended to a primary partition in the unallocated space ?

After that, I want to change MBR to GPT via gdisk. Gdisk automatically delete all partition?

or my partition can be saved like that:
http://slavisa-jovanovic.com/linux/2015/02/19/mbr-to-gpt.html
Do you think its work?

(Its because I cant backup my data so I want to be sure.)

Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Back up data before any major change. & backup partition table info. Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Answer (score 0):

If the ultimate goal is to convert to GPT, there's no point to first doing a logical-to-primary conversion; `gdisk` will read *both* primary and logical partitions and, when you save the partition table, convert them both to GPT partitions. This *assumes,* however, that there are no other problems, such as partitions that overlap GPT data structures or damaged MBR partition table structures. As oldfred points out, the official `gdisk` documentation provides explicit instructions on how to perform this conversion:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

(Note that I'm the author of `gdisk`.)

If you want to do a logical-to-primary conversion *without* converting to GPT, or if you need to do a logical-to-primary conversion as a temporary measure before converting to GPT, you can do so with FixParts (`fixparts`), which is provided as part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu. See the [official FixParts documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) for information on how to do this. Note that there are some caveats and limitations, but it looks like your `/dev/sda5` should be easily convertible. As I said, though, doing this as a preliminary to converting to GPT is pointless, since `gdisk` will read both primary and logical partitions and convert them both, if that's possible. (Note that FixParts shares a lot of code with `gdisk`. In particular, both read MBR partition tables in the same way.)